# checking double down in black jack

Tags: java

In a blackjack game I give a user prompt to choose if he wants to double down:

```
while(true){
    if(players[i].doubledown == true){
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Want to double down?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n");
    dd  = IO.readInt();
    if (dd != 1 && dd!= 2){
        IO.reportBadInput();
    }else{
        break;
    }
} 
int x = 0;
if (dd!=1 && players[i].doubledown == false){
    System.out.print("Choose your next move, " + players[i].name + ": \n" + "Points: " + players[i].points + "\n" + "Hint: ");
    getHints(players[i]);
    System.out.print( "\n1)Hit\n2)Stand\n");
    System.out.println();
    x = IO.readInt();
}else if(dd == 1 && players[i].doubledown == true){
    x = 2;
}else if( dd== 1 && players[i].doubledown == false){
    x = 1;
    players[i].doubledown = true;
}




if(x ==2 || x ==1){
    //
    //Stand or Bust
    //

}
```

For some reason it keeps asking me to double down and then after that it's player 2's turn. Why? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This code will always ask the player to double down, if `players[i].doubledown` is `false`. You don't show us the code where you set that flag, so I assume it's always false if it keeps asking you.

If you then answer `1`, it goes into the 3rd case of your if statement, which doesn't print anything, so I assume that would make it player 2's turn. If you answer `2`, it should ask you to hit or stand... does that happen?

Comment: i did check, i first set players[i].doubledown = false and true if dd==1 and i also checkif(players[i].doubledown == true){
        break;
    }

Comment: what do you mean?  You don't show us the code where you check that flag,?

Comment: The code begins in the `while` loop... you don't show us where that variable is set.